# How to iterate over a collection of associated items in a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

```
class WorkPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :work_plan_tasks
end 

class WorkPlanTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :work_plan
end
```

My form and index actions all work as expected with the associations.

I'm trying to modify the show view for a work plan such that it displays the work plan tasks that belongs to the work plan in question.

I added the code below at the bottom of my show view for work plans, but it keeps blowing up and I've spent far too much time tinkering with the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<% @work_plan.work_plan_task in @work_plan_task %>
    <%= work_plan_task.task_name %?
<% end %>
```

Comment: Off-topic: Think about your model names. If `WorkPlanTask` belongs to `WorkPlan` then you can just call it `Task`. Then it will flow so much better ie first line would read `<% @work_plan.tasks do |task| %>`

Comment: Veritas1 - thanks for the comment and I agree.  The only reason I went as specific as I did was because I have another kind of task elsewhere in the application with different parameters, so just went with the past of least resistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not generally how you loop through items in Rails views. Try this:

```
<% @work_plan.work_plan_tasks.each do |work_plan_task| %>
    <%= work_plan_task.task_name %>
<% end %>
```

The `each` call does what you expect: go through the array, passing the item via `work_plan_task` into the loop.

If you wanted to do it the way you were writing it, you have the syntax backward.

```
<% for work_plan_task in @work_plan.work_plan_tasks %>
    <%= work_plan_task.task_name %>
<% end %>
```

... though honestly I don't even know if that would work, I've never actually tried. :-)

Finally, notice that `@work_plan_task` and `work_plan_task` are different variables.

Comment: Top recommendation worked like a charm - thanks for the help!